# How do I extend the processor's statistic time window ?

Tags: apache-nifi

In apache NIFI some values are set to 5 minutes.
Bulletin board drops it messages after 5 minutes they are published, processor statistics are computed on a 5 minutes window.
How Can I change these setting to something other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this HCC answer](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/75797/is-it-possible-to-get-nifi-processor-stats-metrics.html) these time windows are not configurable.

You can look into tracking your own statistics, but this is likely to be quite challenging.